# ServletContext.getResource to get resource from within lib

Tags: java, tomcat, jakarta-ee, jar

I have a jar-file test.jar that is placed within WEB-INF/lib and contains a single file in its root:

```
/
|- test.jsp
```

Now i would like to access this file from somewhere in my code:

```
this.getServletContext().getResource("/test.jsp");
```

But the result is always null although the documentation of getResource states that the jar-files within WEB-INF/lib are also searched:

http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html#getResource%28java.lang.String%29

Am i missing something or why can't i get the resource?

Answer (score 1):

You already provided the link to the javadoc, quoting the relevant part:

> The path must begin with a `/` and is interpreted as relative to the current context root, or **relative to the `/META-INF/resources` directory of a JAR file** inside the web application's `/WEB-INF/lib` directory.

So it is interpreted as relative to the `/META-INF/resources` folder in a jar file.

However you indicated with a tag that you are using Tomcat. Tomcat implementation of the [`ServletContext.getResource()`](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/servletapi/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html#getResource(java.lang.String)) is somewhat different. It doesn't even mention the resource is searched in jar files.

Suggestion: don't put your resources in jar files if you want to access them with `ServletContext.getResource()`. If you do need to put them into jar files, then instead use the `Class.getResource()` method, e.g. put an optionally empty class into the jar file, and use that to access/load the resource, for example:

Jar content:

```
/
|- SomeClass.class
|- test.jsp
```

Java code to access `test.jsp`:

```
SomeClass.class.getResource("/test.jsp"); // or it can even be "test.jsp"
```

Comment: Ouch... thanks for pointing me the that. But i changed the directory to /META-INF/resources/test.jsp and still get only null from getResource.

Comment: Edited my answer, Tomcat seems to be different.

Comment: I already noticed Tomcat not to mention the jar-scanning in their docs but i also tried Resin 4 and it doesn't work there either. I tried the dummy-class and it works. But i can't use that as i don't know which jar-file the resource is in (in the real case).

Answer (score 0):

You can use your thread's class loader to get your file as an `InputStream` like this:

```
Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("test.jsp");
```

The method `getResourceAsStream()` works for any file in the classpath, whether it's in a directory or inside a JAR.